# ¿Como puedo hacer que las coordenadas de dibujo de un cuadrado sea la misma de un circulo?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

decidì mejorar un poco un antiguo juego, y me encontrè este problema:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let width=70,height=70;
let radio=(width+height)/Math.PI;
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.arc(30,30,radio,0,(Math.PI/180)*360,0);
ctx.strokeRect(30,30,width,height);
ctx.stroke();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

El circulo no se dibuja en la misma posicion que el cuadrado.
Resultado esperado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al momento de ver la coliciòn de un circulo con un cuadrado los calculos se me rompen.

Comment: Podrías poner un dibujo del resultado esperado?

Comment: @Yussef listo. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El cuadrado y el círculo no son concéntricos porque la función [arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) toma como posición el centro mientras que [strokeRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeRect) la esquina superior izquierda.

Aprovechando para implementar funciones que dibujen a partir del centro queda así:

```js
function cuadrado(center, size){
    halfSize = { x: size.x / 2, y: size.y / 2 }
    topLeftCorner = { x: center.x - halfSize.x, y: center.y - halfSize.y }
    ctx.strokeRect(topLeftCorner.x, topLeftCorner.y, size.x, size.y)
}

function circulo(center, radius){
    ctx.arc(center.x, center.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
}

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var ctx = c.getContext("2d")
let centro = { x: 50, y: 50 }
let tamaño = { x: 50, y: 50 }
let diámetro = Math.sqrt(tamaño.x * tamaño.x + tamaño.y * tamaño.y)

ctx.moveTo(0,0)
ctx.lineTo(200,100)
sqrt2 = Math.sqrt(2)
cuadrado(centro, tamaño)
circulo(centro, diámetro/2)
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="120" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let width = 70, height = 70;
let dia = Math.sqrt( width * width + height * height );
ctx.arc( 30 + width/2, 30 + height/2,  dia/2, 0, (Math.PI/180) *360, 0 );
ctx.strokeRect( 30, 30, width, height );
ctx.stroke();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

En **dia**, obtenemos el diámetro en base al teorema de Pitágoras, que nos devuelve la hipotenusa del triángulo formado por los lados del cuadrado.
Dado que para el dibujo del circulo, se toma como referencia su centro, ubicamos este sumandole la mitad del lado a la posición del cuadrado.

Answer (score 0):

Solamente hice modificaciones los siguientes cálculos:

```
let radio = (width + height) / 3 + 4;
```

---

```
ctx.arc(65, 65, radio, 0, (Math.PI / 180) * 360, 0);
```

Y obtienes el resultado esperado, ejemplo:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
let width = 70, height = 70;
let radio = (width + height) / 3 + 4;
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.arc(65, 65, radio, 0, (Math.PI / 180) * 360, 0);
ctx.strokeRect(30, 30, width, height);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="120" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: No lo analice correctamente porque me puse a estudiar otra cosa, disculpa. Debo multiplicar por 2 la posicion X y Y para que se centre en el cuadrado?

Comment: No entendí por qué el `+ 4` en el radio

Comment: @DanielBriceño exacto, eso mismo.

Comment: @Pollo es para aumentar la radio del círculo, mientras voy sumando, va aumentando, y así traté de adaptar que el ancho del radio sea exacto entre las esquinas del cuadrado.

Comment: O sea que lo ajustaste a ojo hasta que quedara bien? Digo, no está calculado por una fórmula para cualquier cuadrado, no?

Comment: No, disculpa fue mi error. Si quieres modifico la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: No, la dejaré así, ya tiene mas de 1 respuesta para que cambié completamente la pregunta. Aquí hay otra diferente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582474/como-detectar-una-colisi%c3%b3n-de-un-circulo-y-un-cuadrado